# Jersey Rest service only returning 404's

Tags: javascript, java, maven, tomcat, jersey

For my application I check account data with a REST service. My Java class AuthenticationResource checks this data en sends a key back to the client. Everything worked fine untill I tried to rush it onto gitHub. this messed up my project and i had to do some parts over.
Now everything is like it was before it broke. But the REST service keeps sending 404's.

I tried to change everything in the web.xml and the pom.xml, but that didn't work. I also checked the java class itself. I could not see any problems

this is the AuthenticationResource.Java:

```
package nl.hu.v1ipass.barapp.webservices;

@Path("/authentication")
public class AuthenticationResource {
  final static public SecretKey key = MacProvider.generateKey();

  @POST
  @Produces("application/json")
  public Response authenticateUser( @FormParam("kassanummer") int kassa,
                                    @FormParam("username") int username, 
                                    @FormParam("password") String password) throws SQLException {
    try {
      // Authenticate the user against the database
      UserPostgressDaoImpl dao = new UserPostgressDaoImpl();
      String role = dao.findRoleForUser(kassa, username, password);

      if (role == null) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("No user found!");  } 

      String token = createToken(Integer.toString(username), role);

      SimpleEntry<String, String> JWT = new SimpleEntry<String, String>("JWT", token);
      return Response.ok(JWT).build();


    } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) 
        { return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build(); }
  }

  private String createToken(String username, String role) throws JwtException {
        Calendar expiration = Calendar.getInstance();
        expiration.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        return Jwts.builder()
          .setSubject(username)
          .setExpiration(expiration.getTime())
          .claim("role", role)
          .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key)
          .compact();
      }
}
```

My Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>nl.hu.v1ipass.barapp.webservices</param-value>
        </init-param> 

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature
            </param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And finaly my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.hu.v1ipass</groupId>
    <artifactId>barapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>barapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I hope someone sees what I'm doing wrong, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try removing the old resources then cleaning the server, and then redeploying?

Comment: yes I did, that's why I think it's rather strange why the service isn't woking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Ensure the server is started correctly on the specified port.
2.Make sure no other application is running on the your port
if the above 2 steps are working fine then start debugging 
3.Ensure execution point is reaching inside the  specific method by putting a debug point in the first line of the method
4.Debug line by line and check if any resource or path is missing

Answer (score 0):

All looks good, something to suspect is when the server starts up.
Have you seen any error/exception in the trace which can help you to diagnose further?

Comment: everything seems normal when the server starts up, not a single error.

Comment: That's the hard part about this problem. There are no errors or something weird in the code. I've been trying to fix this for 4 hours now.